There is no variable named 'var' : terraform error using for 'each'
i'm getting this error while trying to create an application gateway with terraform and azure, so here is error  :

│ Error: Unknown variable
│ 
│   on ../../../../../sca-terraform-modules/modules/ApplicationGateway/main.tf line 157, in resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "AG":
│  157:     for_each = var.IS_CUSTOM_NAMING ? {} : var.BACKEND_CONFIGURATION
│ 
│ There is no variable named "var".

│ Error: Unknown variable
│ 
│   on ../../../../../sca-terraform-modules/modules/ApplicationGateway/main.tf line 148, in resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "AG":
│  148:     for_each = var.IS_CUSTOM_NAMING ? var.BACKEND_ADDRESS_POOL_CONFIGURATION : []
│ 
│ There is no variable named "var".

│ Error: Insufficient backend_address_pool blocks
│ 
│   on ../../../../../sca-terraform-modules/modules/ApplicationGateway/main.tf line 32, in resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "AG":
│   32: resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "AG" {
│ 
│ At least 1 "backend_address_pool" blocks are require


here is my code :
dynamic "backend_address_pool" {
    for_each = var.IS_CUSTOM_NAMING ? var.BACKEND_ADDRESS_POOL_CONFIGURATION : []
    content {
      name         = backend_address_pool.value.name
      ip_addresses = backend_address_pool.value.backend_address_pool_ips
      fqdns        = backend_address_pool.value.backend_address_pool_fqdns
    }
  }

dynamic "backend_address_pool" {
    for_each = var.IS_CUSTOM_NAMING ? {} : var.BACKEND_CONFIGURATION
    content {
      name         = "beap-agw-${backend_address_pool.key}"
      ip_addresses = backend_address_pool.value.backend_pool_ips
      fqdns        = backend_address_pool.value.backend_pool_fqdns

    }
  }
variable "BACKEND_ADDRESS_POOL_CONFIGURATION" {
  type = list(object({
    name                       = string
    backend_address_pool_ips   = optional(list(string))
    backend_address_pool_fqdns = optional(list(string))
  }))
  default     = []
  description = "Definition of Backend Address Pools."
}
variable "BACKEND_CONFIGURATION" {
  type = map(object({
    backend_pool_ips                                = optional(list(string))
    backend_pool_fqdns                              = optional(list(string))
    backend_cookie_affinity                         = string
    backend_path                                    = optional(string)
    backend_port                                    = number
    backend_protocol                                = string
    backend_request_timeout                         = optional(number)
    trusted_root_certificate_names                  = optional(list(string), [])
    pick_host_name_from_backend_address             = optional(bool)
    probe_interval                                  = optional(number)
    probe_protocol                                  = optional(string)
    probe_path                                      = optional(string)
    probe_timeout                                   = optional(number)
    probe_unhealthy_threshold                       = optional(number)
    probe_port                                      = optional(number)
    probe_host                                      = optional(string)
    probe_match_body                                = optional(string)
    probe_match_status_code                         = optional(list(string))
    probe_pick_host_name_from_backend_http_settings = optional(bool)

  }))
  default     = {}
  description = "Provide settings for Application Gateway backend pool."
}

I'm new with terraform

Your first two errors say there is an undefined var called var.  Try searching "var.var" in your code.

Actually it's somthing i've got while using the loop for each, but i did search there is no var.var in the code

Since you are new, try narrowing the scope a bit.  Try doing one backend pool first.  Work with a local static defition of the pool to make sure you got the for loop functional.

Good point, i will start with one backend pool first thank you
